# Unstandardised slopes in MuMIN package

Tags: r, lme4, standardized, mumin

I used the `MuMIN` package to do a model averaging based on information criterion, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059697/standardisation-in-mumin-package-in-r).

```
options(na.action = "na.fail")
```

Create a global model with all variables and two way interaction:

```
global.model<-lmer(yld.res ~ rain + brk + 
  onset + wid + (1|state),data=data1,REML="FALSE")
```

Standardise the glboal model since the variables are on different scale

```
stdz.model <- standardize(global.model,standardize.y = TRUE)
```

Create all possible combinations of the model

```
model.set <- dredge(stdz.model)
```

Get the best model based on deltaAICc<2 criteria

```
top.models <- get.models(model.set, subset= delta<2)
```

Average the models to calculate the effect size (standardised slopes of the input variables)

```
s<-model.avg(top.models) 
summary(s);confint(s)
```

The effect size of the variables are as follows:

```
Variable           slope estimate
brk                 -0.28
rain                 0.13
wid                  0.10
onset                0.09
```

As you can see, I had standardize my model in step 3 so I can compare these slope estimates i.e. I can say slope estimate of `brk` is greater (in negative direction) than `rain`. However, since these slope estimates where standardised, I wanted to know if there is any way I can get the unstandardised slopes?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642111/how-to-unscale-the-coefficients-from-an-lmer-model-fitted-with-a-scaled-respon/23643740#23643740

Comment: Many thanks for this. I referred to the link you directed and it is exactly what I was looking for you. But what does the symbol like `Y0`,`mu0`,`b0` mean in these equations `(Y0-mu0)/s0 = b0' + (b1'*(1/s1*(x1-mu1))) + b2'*(1/s2*(x2-mu2))+ ` . Is there any text book that I can refer to? Thanks a lot again